# Why did the Fisher scoring algorithm not converge after adjusting?

Tags: r, metafor

We are using the the `metafor` package for meta analysis. In one of our analyses we got the error:

> Fisher scoring algorithm did not converge

We tried using this code to adjust it:

```
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, (control = list(stepadj = 0.5)))
```

It worked in the past, but now it is not working, even when changing the code to:

```
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, (control = list(stepadj = 0.5, maxiter=10000)))
```

We are still getting the same error:

> Fisher scoring algorithm did not converge

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the superfluous parentheses. This should work:

```
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, control=list(stepadj=0.5, maxiter=10000))
```

Comment: that's interesting.  Why does it make a difference in this context?

Comment: The parentheses turn the `(control = ...)` part into an unnamed argument, so it ends up getting matched by position to who-knows what ... Try this:

`f <- function(x, y, z) {
   if (!missing(x)) print(paste("x =", x)); if (!missing(y)) print(paste("y =", y)); if (!missing(z)) print(paste("z =", z))
}` and then `f(1, z=3)` versus `f(1, (z=3))`.

Comment: a nice counterexample to "you can put parentheses around anything and it doesn't change the meaning"

Comment: Yeah, had to think about that one for a bit, but now it makes sense.